# Can´t install a new version of ruby using rvm in Mojave

Tags: ruby, rvm

I tried to install a new version of ruby using RVM,
`rvm install 2.5.0`
but during configure process the installation fails

```
Error running ‘./configure --prefix=/Users/evelinponce/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/zlib:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared’,
please read /Users/evelinponce/.rvm/log/1574200398_ruby-2.5.0/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

configure.log

```
...
checking whether CFLAGS is valid... yes
checking whether LDFLAGS is valid... no
configure: error: something wrong with LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6/lib"
```

RVM version: rvm 1.29.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remembered that in the last weeks I upgraded mysql from 5.6 to 5.7 so in the bash file I had some mysql5.6 configurations blocking the ruby installation. Only what I need to do was delete from bash profile the lines related with mysql5.6

Open bash file

```
nano .bash_profile
```

Delete

> LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6/lib"

Reload bash or open other terminal

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 2):

After trying everything, [this](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/590#issuecomment-810473148) answer is the only one that helped me:

```
LIBRARY_PATH="" rvm install X.X.X
```

Works with `rvm upgrade` too!